# All flowering plants gives fruits. Why does jasmine flower plant not yield fruits?

Tags: genetics

My question is actually my long term doubt. I have seen most of the flowers turning into fruits. But why not this jasmine flower?

Comment: I'm sure they do, unless some genetically modified to hinder fertilisation. Interesting are Banana & sugarcane plants.

Comment: They do make berries - they are red to violet. See [here](http://www.efloras.org/florataxon.aspx?flora_id=2&taxon_id=200017787).

Answer (score 7):

Flower gives rise to seeds and fruits which are the ways through them the plant distributes the seeds.

Here, one should differentiate botanic term "fruit" and general common meaning of the word "fruit" which are not the same.

Botanic fruit can be subtle, not fleshy and come as a grain or pods.

Jasmine fruits are black berries.

[image]